# What kind of mailing lists do academics use?

Tags: email, communication

I have to create a mailing list. One of those kinds that are used in academia, with just one address through which anybody can share an email with everybody included in the mailing list. I've searched online, but basically most of answers usually refer to marketing mailing lists. How do I find such mailing-list services?

---

The mailing list is thought for sharing urban-regeneration related news through an open mailing-list of organizations: universities, privates, foundations. However, the mailing-list is not hosted by a university, and would like to understand a viable alternative. To be precise, I asked this question in the Academia Stack since I have found this type of mailing-lists only in academic fields, and wanted to understand whether there was a way for anybody to setup such type of mailing list.

Comment: Why don't you talk to your IT department? They should be able to set up one for you.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, I am not in Academia currently :( I mean, it's for a personal project

Comment: You should ask the IT department for advice. You shouldn't just use some list server recommended by someone on the internet. In some countries people are strongly discouraged from using commercial services (and Google services in particular) for this due to data privacy considerations.

Comment: Am I being downvoted for it is the wrong Stack?

Comment: Ignore down votes. People have their own reasons. But maybe because you say you aren't in academia.

Comment: Maybe because this is about mailing lists, not academia, and it is a shopping question? ("Can anybody give me a few names of such mailing-lists?")  If someone in academia would ask how to set up a mailing list, I would also deem it off-topic. Otherwise, people start asking for help on latex and so forth ...

Answer (score 2):

All my research-related mailinglists seem to use [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/).

[This guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9400082?hl=en) tells you how to set up a mailinglist there.

Comment: But beware that Google often makes some of its services obsolete with little notice. Prepare for that, or find something that you can host yourself.

Comment: @Buffy, yes. That is basically the problem. For storage space there is not that much of a problem I suppose: you just pay a server. However, I can't understand how this may be achieved, since this type of mailing-list is not just an email to multiple recipients, but something more sophisticated.

Comment: I own a few domains and my service provider will give me access to such things. The overall cost is probably a few hundred dollars per year including domain registration. Your profile suggests you may already have a domain.

Comment: Though the OP may not have a domain already.